# How to use Firestore to continuously write new data from a 3rd party API and ignore old data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am running into some trouble implementing some code in python to send data to Firestore. I am trying to learn Firestore by building a small weather pet project. My code continuously queries a 3rd party weather API and receives a dictionary of JSON objects where each JSON object represents the weather from 8 am today to the current time today for a specific city. Usually there is a new data point added to the API every 30 minutes to show how the weather and humidity have changed, so it's not too much data (i.e. one datapoint for 8 am, one for 8:30 am, and so on). I then try to send this data to firestore. My firestore has a collection named "Weather" and under this collection are many documents with the name "Weather - San Francisco, California from 8 am to current time", "Weather - Austin, Texas from 8 am to current time - Date: 9/1/2021 ", etc. Each document should be a list of JSON objects (or, I can go with a dictionary of dictionaries, where the key is the time, whatever is easier to implement) where each object represents the weather for a specific time (i.e. 8 am, 8:30 am, 9 am). The problem I am running into in writing the code to write to Firestore is that I am doing way too many read/write calls (expensive) since my code to write to Firestore runs continuously and a lot of the data in the response from the 3rd party API is past data which keeps being written over and over to Firestore. I would ideally like to ignore the old weather data which should already exist in Firestore, and only write new weather data. My code:

```
    # wd is our list of weather data for from 8 am today to current time today for many cities where each element looks like: 
    # ("Weather", "Weather - Austin Texas from  8 am to current time - Date: 8/25/2021", {"weather": "95 degrees F", time: "9:30 am PST"})
    # ("Weather", "Weather - Atlanta Georgia from  8 am to current time - Date: 8/25/2021", {"weather": "72 degrees F", time: "11:30 am PST"})

    for wd in write_data:
                ref = firestore.client().collection(wd[0]).document(wd[1])
                doc = ref.get()
                if doc.exists:
                    # append new item to list. 
                    # The goal here is to only add new items to list, ignoring old items. 
                    # I thought firestore.ArrayUnion would only add new items.
                    ref.set({“weather” : firestore.ArrayUnion([wd[2]])}) 
                else:
                    ref.set({“weather”: [wd[2]]}) #  add the first item to list
```

The code above doesn’t work. It doesn’t give the end result that I expect. It continuously writes some data, then overwrites itself, and it's expensive because it is doing many unnecessary calls. Would love some pointers in the right direction. Thanks!